# Ubuntu 17.10 public hotspot problem

Tags: 17.10, resolv.conf

So /etc/resolv.conf doesn't help if i put googles DNS 8.8.8.8

I have public hotspot network were this pc has to work and Artful 17.10 can't connect to that through browser.

Error resolving : Name or service not known (using firefox 57 Quantum)

Comment: Is the public hotspot working on other devices, i.e your mobile phone?

Comment: Yes it is. Also i have one Linux mint Desktop and it is also working in same hotspot. Hmm Maybe the problem is Firefox? it is saying something about bad certification?

Comment: Are you required to log in when you first join this hotspot?

Comment: Also, what happens if you use the default DNS servers provided by the hotspot?

Comment: You have to login in that Hotspot, but Ubuntu + Firefox won't let you so far that you could type something because of that resolving error. Nothing happens with different DNS. Gives same error.